# Phonegap 2.2 error creating Android project

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I'm trying to create a project with phonegap 2.2, everyting works fine until I execute de "create" statement. I throws the following error:

```
Creating new android project...
Copying js, jar & config.xml files...
Copying cordova command tools...
Updating AndroidManifest.xml and Main Activity...
create.js<31,5> Runtime error in Microsoft JScript: Access route not found
```

And then the project gets created, but opening it with eclipse throws the following error:

```
<BIG RED X> Invalid project description 
Reason: Invalid project description
```

Don't have any idea why this is happening...

Answer (score 5):

In

**Eclipse Help > install new software**

The `Name` field is optional, `MDS AppLaud 1.2` suggested

In `Location`, enter the download site:

```
http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download
```

Then hit

**Select OK**

and finally

**Accept all**.
[image]